# Kendo UI DropBox inside a grid not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, grid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi can anyone help me out i am struggling with my code. i am trying since two days how to add dropdown in a grid i am trying to fix my code but i am not able to find out why drop box in not displaying in my grid my code is

```
<%: Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoGridAjaxEditing2.Models.ProductViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(product => product.CustomerID).Width(100);
              columns.Bound(product => product.CustomerName).ClientTemplate("#=Category.CustomerFName#").Width(160);
              columns.Bound(product => product.CustomerLastName);
              columns.Bound(product => product.Customerage).Width(250);


              columns.Command(commands =>
              {
                  commands.Edit(); // The "edit" command will edit and update data items
                  commands.Destroy(); // The "destroy" command removes data items
              }).Title("Commands").Width(200);
          })
          .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create()) // The "create" command adds new data items
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)) // Use inline editing mode
          .DataSource(dataSource =>
              dataSource.Ajax()
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(product => product.CustomerID); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model
                    model.Field(product => product.CustomerID).Editable(false); // Make the ProductID property not editable
                    model.Field(p => p.Category).DefaultValue(
                          ViewData["defaultCategory"] as KendoGridAjaxEditing2.Models.ClientCategoryViewModel);

                })
                .Create(create => create.Action("Products_Create", "Home")) // Action invoked when the user saves a new data item
                .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home"))  // Action invoked when the grid needs data
                .Update(update => update.Action("Products_Update", "Home"))  // Action invoked when the user saves an updated data item
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Products_Destroy", "Home")) // Action invoked when the user removes a data item
          )
          .Pageable()
%>
```

and HomeController method

```
 private void PopulateCategories()
    {
        var dataContext = new NorthwindEntities();
        var categories = dataContext.Customer_details
                    .Select(c => new ClientCategoryViewModel
                    {
                         ID = c.ID,
                         CustomerFName = c.name
                    })
                    .OrderBy(e => e.CustomerFName);
        ViewData["categories"] = categories;
        ViewData["defaultCategory"] = categories.First();
    }

   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
       PopulateCategories();
        return View();
    }
```

and my ClientCategoryViewModel class

```
 public class ClientCategoryViewModel
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerFName { get; set; }
}
```

When i am trying  .ClientTemplate("#=Category.CustomerFName#").Width(160); in my view i am getting no result but once i remove it my grid is displaying records but i am not able to understand why i am not getting dropdown inside my grid and i am trying this last 2 to 3 days and i am not able to find out a solution i have tried to look at this link as a guide http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html but problem is still there please someone help me out thanks

Answer (score 0):

ClientTemplate is for display mode, for editing mode you need to create DropDownList editor. Check the following topic for [more information](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/editor-templates). If you follow the instructions from there you should make it work.

Comment: i am not able to display as well it is displaying as a textbox and the link you send it its not linked with grid i am new in mvc so i need a help please

Answer (score 0):

You need to use columns.ForeignKey as shown in this demo: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/foreignkeycolumn.html

Be sure you have the GridForeignKey.cshtml editor template.(typically this is in Views\Shared\EditorTemplates)

You'll most likely want to bind it to your CustomerId rather than the name.
I typically bind to an IEnumerable.  For some reason Kendo makes you tell it that "Value" is the value column and "Text" is the text column even though they don't make you do that for a normal, non-grid drop down.

If you need to let it be blank, bind it to something along these lines:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PaymentTermsList
        {
            get
            {
                if (paymentTermsList == null)
                {
                    paymentTermsList = 
                        new [] { new SelectListItem(){ Value = "-1", Text = "(None)" } }.Concat(
                            referenceDataService.GetActivePaymentTerms()
                                .Select(pt => new SelectListItem() { Value = pt.PaymentTermId.ToString(), Text = pt.Name }));
                }
                return paymentTermsList;
            }
        }
```